# Changes in my CSS aren't showing on the webpage, how do I link the classes properly

Tags: html, css, navbar

changed "div" tags into more semantic html tags to make a webpage more user friendly but unsure how to change CSS to make these new semantic tags inline on the webpage as well as change other styling aspects of the code. How do i make sure the right elements in my html is linked to the right css code. Sorry if im not using the terms correctly new to coding.

I tried changing the class names to the corresponding more semantic tags so that i could change the webpage style

Answer (score 0):

In HTML we can link css to the html file in the header like so:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
```

Where styles.css is the stylesheet file.

On your html tags for example

```
<div></div>
```

You are able to add classes which links these tags/containers to a specific style in your style sheet.
For example In HTML:

```
<div class="myclass"></div>
```

the class "myclass" is the linker towards this in your stylesheet:

```
.myclass:
   color: red;
```

the full stop signifies that you are linking this to a class in the html, you can also do this with id="myid" and using a # instead of full stop, however i prefer to keep my ID purely for scripting use and classes for styling

Read more and learn a bit more about this at w3: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_css.asp

Comment: Apologies I dont think i worded my question that well but i did find a solution in the end the problem was a mistype which is why the html and css weren't corresponding. Thank you for the help regardless!

Answer (score 0):

Html elements and class attributes are two different things. Both can be targeted using CSS.

For example:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div class=“name-of-class”></div
  </body
</html>
```

There are three html elements (html, body and a div). And the div has a class attribute of “name-of-class”.

You can target the elements as well as the classes with css:

```
body {
  background-color: black;
}

.name-of-class {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

To target the elements simply write the name of the tag without brackets. And to target the element with the class add a period before name of the class.

If you change an element or class name on your HTML, make sure to update your CSS styles or file to match.

Hope this helps, if you still have doubts paste some of your code to give it a check out.

Comment: I think i understand the concept of css, its just i have a pre written code which i am editing and i think when downloading the css onto my local system I've svaed it to the wrong file or maybe linked it incorrectly       my code:  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css">
    <title>Horiseon |Search engine optomisation, Online reputation management, Social media marketing</title>
</head>
 old code:  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./assets/css/style.css">
    <title>website</title>
</head>

Comment: But also it could be because i changed a all of "DIV" elements to make them more specific/ semantic and now they don't match up with the style sheets

Comment: The old code--------------------                                                                              
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./assets/css/style.css">
    <title>website</title>
</head>

Comment: my new code                                                                                                           
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css">
    <title>Horiseon |Search engine optomisation, Online reputation management, Social media marketing</title>
</head>

Comment: Okay, this is a bit clearer.

First of all, yes, the **href** attribute in the “old code” is pointing to a folder structure to link the css file. It’s going through an assets folder and then a css folder where the style.css file is located.
In your new code since you’ve only established href=“stylesheet.css”, both your index.html and your stylesheet.css files should be in the same folder for the link to work properly.

Furthermore, in response to changing the **div** elements to more specific/semantic names, you will have to match the styles accordingly as well.